# Custom scrollbar only in one div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I want to have a custom scroll bar in Chrome.

So, I'm using this sass:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  border-radius: 3px;

  &:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  }
}
```

My problem is that I want this scrollbar style only in an specific div. But if I do:

```
#boardslist {

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    border-radius: 3px;

    &:hover {
      background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    }
  }

}
```

is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: You can customize it ever **better** with [**fakeScroll**](https://github.com/yairEO/fakescroll) (vanilla lightweight script)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
#boardslist {

  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 0.5em;
   height: 0.5em;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
   border-radius: 3px;

   &:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
   }
  }
}
```

Check this out http://codepen.io/tholman/pen/tldwm

Comment: But you can't drag the scrollbar the right way (or click arrows) on iOS Safari it seems.

Comment: That would be nice to add an explanation as to *why* this works as well.

Answer (score 27):

If you are doing it for a class, you can do it in the following way. Side bar is the class given to the div that you want to allow scrolling.

```
.side_bar{
    padding-right: 20px; 
    margin-left: -12px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /* width */

}
.side_bar::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5px;
    }

    /* Track */
.side_bar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px grey; 
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /* Handle */
.side_bar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: rgb(7, 7, 7); 
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /* Handle on hover */
.side_bar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #009eb3; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's 2020 and `::-webkit-scrollbar` is still not supported in Firefox. 
Besides `overflow:auto` shows scrollbar when content overflows in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox there will be no visible scrollbar until we start scrolling. Go guess whether content is scrollable or not. Same with `overflow:scroll`. Not very intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 2022 and still no support in Firefox: 
https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar

However, basics can be customized in Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars
https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollbar-color

```
/* Chrome */
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  /*background-color: grey;*/
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: orange; 
  border-radius: 15px;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

/*.container::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background-color: red;
   border-radius: 15px;
}*/

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: red; 
}

/* IE */
.container {
  scrollbar-face-color: orange; 
  scrollbar-shadow-color: grey; 
  scrollbar-highlight-color: red;
}

/* FireFox */
.container {
  scrollbar-color: orange grey;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

/* View Scrollbar */
.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width:400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Working example is here:
https://codepen.io/svigir/pen/LYOOjyj