# How can I customize the browser scroll bar for specific parts in a web page?

Tags: html, css

I need to reduce the scroll bar width in my web page but not for the whole page. I am using one splitter and a grid in that page if height exceeds scrollbar occurs. How can I reduce the width of it. I have used the following styles

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 5px;
  }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
 }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
 }
```

But these styles are applying for the whole page. Can anyone suggest me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You probably want to look at [this](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbar) and reconsider using that.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38024073/9387017

Comment: try `div.class ::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 5px; }`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a class for parts of the webpage where you want to customize the scroll bar. For that class, let us say `class='customScroll'`, you could define your css code:

```
.cuctomScroll {
    overflow: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: 20px; */for Mozilla support/*
}
.customScroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px; */for Chrome and IE support/*
}
```

**Edit 1**: Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/43o50m6a/6/.
Please feel free to ask any further clarifications.

Comment: I have tried that already but it was not working is there any other solution to fix that issue

Comment: Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/43o50m6a/6/. Please feel free to ask any further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}
```

More information: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp