# How to maintain Vertical Scroll with bottom Box

Tags: css

[image]
[image]

Like that image I need to maintain the bottom box of the vertical scroll bar...

here is the **code** I used...

```css
div {
        border:1px solid black;
        width:400px;
        height:110px;
        overflow-x:scroll;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>New Item</li>
            <li>New Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="append">Add Item</button>
```

Comment: you can simply remove scroll-y: property

Comment: Please explain better what do you want beacause it's not clear. P.s. i don't knwo why you get a downvote

Comment: Either use `overflow-x: auto` or remove it entirely.

Comment: i always need to maintain the right bottom box... if remove scroll-y it dont...

Comment: Those "boxes" are platform dependant. On MacOS and iOS they will _never_ be present, no matter what overflow styles are used.

Comment: is there any possibility to reduce height of vertical scroll...

Comment: [Custom scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023932/custom-scrollbar-only-in-one-div)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function appendItem(){
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("New Item"));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
div {
        border:1px solid black;
        height:110px;
        width:300px;
        overflow:auto;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <ul id='list'>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>New Item</li>
            <li>New Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button onclick='appendItem()'>Add Item</button>
```

Comment: thank you for you answer... but I have trouble on CSS... not adding item by using js... please see the above images...

Comment: you can check the above snippet for adding items.

Comment: yes... but that part I did already... but the question about css... thanks...

Comment: can you explain the problem?

Comment: see the second image... that's what I looking for...